# Radomly black screens only on train rides!

Tags: 16.04, crash

I am experiencing the weirdest behavior with my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04:

Everything is working fine when I am at home or at my parents place. But when I am riding the train (what I do a lot) the screen randomly turns black. The system is still up and running (I can hear music still running), but the screen is black. This ONLY happens when I am in the train and it is driving me nuts.

I have ruled out a hardware problem, because when I hit the sleep-button on my keyboard (FN + ESC), the screen comes back for a fraction of a second before the system is going into sleep mode. This wouldn't happen, if it was a hardware issue.

I am thinking that the problem might be the missing network connection. Maybe the network manager "goes to sleep" and somehow kills another process? But then again, it happens so randomly, sometimes after 5 minutes, sometimes after an hour. Ones the screen is black, if I close the lid (go to sleep) and then open it again, the image is back.

My girlfriend has the same laptop running the same Ubuntu and it's also happening for her, although not that often.

I am pretty new to the Linux-World and would really appreciate your thoughts on this problem. Please let me know, if you need further details or log-files.

Comment: is the train very bumpy? if it were, the hard drive in your laptop could be automatically turning itself off to avoid harming itself. (hard drives and bumps dont mix) and your music could still play in that scenario, because a lot of music players load the music into ram.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most answer-like answer, but it is too long to put into a comment.

> I have ruled out a hardware problem, because when I hit the sleep-button on my keyboard (FN + ESC), the screen comes back for a fraction of a second before the system is going into sleep mode. **This wouldn't happen, if it was a hardware issue.**

If anything, this *points* to a hardware problem. It certainly doesn't disprove one. Zalgo is most likely onto something with the hard drive. While I'm glad you're thinking (most questions here are from people who think Googling is beneath them), I'm not exactly sure what you were thinking or what logic you used to arrive to this conclusion.

You haven't told us the model of the laptop, but I had an HP ProBook for a while, and one of its cool features was that it had an accelerometer in it. If that accelerometer detected sudden motion, it would park the hard drive (if it was supported) so as to avoid any damage to the disks after a fall or bang.

It's possible your laptop has this same feature. If the train is not the smoothest, and the ride is bumpy, then the accelerometer may be detecting this as a fall and parking the drive. That can certainly cause the screen to black out.

Hitting the sleep shortcut probably forces the drive back into operation, so the OS can read from it and sleep. That would make the screen come on for a second, since the hard drive is running again.

> I am thinking that the problem might be the missing network connection. Maybe the network manager "goes to sleep" and somehow kills another process? But then again, it happens so randomly, sometimes after 5 minutes, sometimes after an hour. Ones the screen is black, if I close the lid (go to sleep) and then open it again, the image is back.

This is highly unlikely. If Ubuntu caused the screen to black out whenever there was no network connection, I'm fairly certain this question would not have been my first time hearing about it.

I think the most likely culprit is some overactive hard drive safety feature, or just bad casing for the drive bay. If it's the former, you may be able to turn it off in the BIOS settings (if it exists). If your computer has no such feature, then you might want to bring the laptops into a repair shop, or at least research if this is a known defect.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thank you very much for your input! Yesterday it happened for the first time outside of a train. I had the laptop on my lap and there  was no movement at all. I also checked the BIOS for a safety feature, there is none. Also i am using an SSD, so movement shouldn't be that much of an issue, right? 

I am still thinking it's more likely to be a software issue, especially after it happened yesterday on the couch. I tried looking into the syslog, but I am pretty new to to the Linux world, so I was a little bit overwhelmed...

Comment: @Nasemann Oh, SSD. Well, then it's probably not an accelerometer thing. However, I've never seen this problem before and the fact that it happens on two of the same model is even weirder. Can you install Windows on one and see if it has the same issues?

Comment: @Zacharee1 The only reason to get a laptop with Ubuntu was to get rid of Windows ;-) But I guess that would be the best way to see if it is really Software/Ubuntu related. I will give it a try, but probably not before next weekend. Thank you!